# The Javascript promise does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Here I declared my promise.

```
   const fetchmessage= new Promise(
            (resolve,reject)=>{
              this.props.authStore.verifyLocalToken();
              console.log("VLT Resolve");
              resolve("Completed");
            }
            );

          fetchmessage.then(this.props.inboxStore.inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber,firebaseToken));
```

The following is my **verifyLocalToken** code

```
   verifyLocalToken() {
    console.log("VerifyLT - Start");
        fetch('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/api/VerifyLocalToken', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: `mobileNumber=${this.mobileNumber}&key=${this.key}`
        }).then((response) => response.json()).then(
            (responseJson) => {
                console.log("http request v l t --", responseJson);
                this.firebaseToken = responseJson.firebaseToken;
            }).catch(
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        )
        console.log("VerifyLT - Stop");

}
```

Following is my **inboxMessageFetch** code

```
inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber,firebaseToken) {
        console.log("InboxFetch  --", `${mobileNumber}/inbox`,firebaseToken);

            firebase.database().ref(`${mobileNumber}/inbox`)
                .on('value', snapshot => {
                    console.log('FB', snapshot.val());
                })
    }
```

The output is like this [image: Console Log]

Shouldn't 
***http request v l t*** comes before ***InboxFetch  -- 8891468710/inbox undefined***, because HTTP request belongs to the promise and the inbox fetch we asked to run after fetching the HTTP request?

How to refactor the code and make sure the HTTP request completed and then call the inbox fetch function?

Comment: But but... it is a javascript promise

Comment: yeah it is.. what's the problem with Javascript promise?

Comment: It works as expected you just expect it to work like it doesn't work :) Otherwise, you are claiming that there is an essential bug in the ES6 native code that has somehow gone unnoticed until now?

Comment: I don't know. I wanted my code to run as expected. I couldn't find any problem with my code. That's why I asked on SO, by the way I don't understand why my question got downvoted. We shouldn't ask questions like this on SO ?

Comment: Not really, because this is something that's explained in the official docs which means you didn't research before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues here.

1. The line

   ```
   fetchmessage.then(this.props.inboxStore.inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber,firebaseToken));
   ```

   ...**calls** `this.props.inboxStore.inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber,firebaseToken)` and passes its return value into `then`, exactly like `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and then passes its return value into `foo`. You probably meant to pass in a function, e.g.

   ```
   fetchmessage.then(() => this.props.inboxStore.inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber,firebaseToken));
   ```
2. You're not waiting for `verifyLocalToken`'s work, which is asynchronous, to complete before you continue with the execution of `fetchmessage`.
3. (Related to #2) `verifyLocalToken` doesn't provide any way for the caller to know it's work is done; it needs to return a promise.
4. (Related to #2 & #3) You *already* have a promise, from `fetch`, in `verifyLocalToken`; so there's no need to create a new promise to save in `fetchmessage`. Any time you have a promise, use `then`, don't use the `new Promise` anti-pattern.
5. `fetchmessage` sounds like a function name to me, but in your code, it's a variable that will receive a promise, not a function.

Here's roughly how that stuff should look (note the `***` comments):

```
verifyLocalToken() {
    console.log("VerifyLT - Start");
    // *** Return the promise from `then`
    return fetch('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/api/VerifyLocalToken', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: `mobileNumber=${this.mobileNumber}&key=${this.key}`
    }).then((response) => response.json()).then(
        (responseJson) => {
            console.log("http request v l t --", responseJson);
            this.firebaseToken = responseJson.firebaseToken;
        }).catch(
        (error) => {
            console.error(error); // *** You're converting failure to success
                                  // with `undefined` here, which isn't
                                  // a good idea. Re-throw the error.
            throw error;
        })
    // *** If you want to show something when this finishes, do it
    // in a `then` handler
    ).then(value => {
        console.log("VerifyLT - Stop");
        return value;
    });
}
```

Then `fetchmessage`:

```
const fetchmessage = this.props.authStore.verifyLocalToken()
    .then(value => {
        console.log("VLT Resolve");
        return "Completed"; // *** Really convert the value to completed?
    });
```

...and if you want to then separate the call to `then`:

```
fetchmessage.then(result => this.props.inboxStore.inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber, firebaseToken));
```

That's a sketch of what you need to do, **not** meant to be copied-and-pasted directly. Think the changes through and apply them as necessary.

Remember that promises are a *pipeline* where each handler gets to transform the value as it goes through.

Answer (score 2):

```
      fetchmessage.then(this.props.inboxStore.inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber,firebaseToken));
```

This code is directly calling the inboxMessageFetch function and not waiting for the then. I think the correct code is

```
fetchmessage.then(() =>      
    this.props.inboxStore.inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber,firebaseToken);
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make a new promise, but you do need to return the promises from your methods your verifyLocalToken method should look like this

```
 verifyLocalToken() {
    return fetch('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/api/VerifyLocalToken', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: `mobileNumber=${this.mobileNumber}&key=${this.key}`
        }).then((response) => response.json()).then(
            (responseJson) => {
                console.log("http request v l t --", responseJson);
                this.firebaseToken = responseJson.firebaseToken;
            }).catch(
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        )
        console.log("VerifyLT - Stop");

}
```

Then you can just do this

```
const fetchmessage = this.props.authStore.verifyLocalToken();
fetchmessage.then(() => {
    this.props.inboxStore.inboxMessageFetch(mobileNumber,firebaseToken));
}
```